# Exercise about cotangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry

I am trying to solve the following exercise:
Let $Q$ be a manifold, $T^{*}Q$ its cotangent bundle and $\pi:T^{*}Q\rightarrow Q$ the bundle map. Let $\omega$ be the standard symplectic form on $T^{*}Q$. If $B$ is a closed 2-form on $Q$, then one can show that $\omega+\pi^{*}B$ is a symplectic form on $T^{*}Q$.
The question now is: show that there is a symplectomorphism $f:(T^{*}Q,\omega)\rightarrow(T^{*}Q,\omega+\pi^{*}B)$ that is homotopic to the identity map, iff. $B$ is exact.

My progress: if such $f$ exists, then we have $[\omega]=[f^{*}(\omega+\pi^{*}B)]=[\omega+\pi^{*}B]$ by homotopy invariance of de rham cohomology. So $\pi^{*}B$ is exact. How does it follow that $B$ is exact?
For the converse, I would like to apply Moser's theorem to the family of forms $\omega+t\pi^{*}B$, but compactness is needed for that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\pi^{*} B = d \eta$ and $\sigma : M \to T^{*} M$ is the zero section, then $\sigma^{*} \pi^{*} B = d \sigma^{*} \eta$ and hence $B = d \sigma^{*} \eta$.

As for your Moser trick, I think you can bruteforce through the proof of Moser to check that the obtained vector field is complete. In your case, with $\omega_t = \omega + t \pi^{*} B$, we see that $\frac{d}{dt} \omega_t = \pi^{*} B = d \pi^{*} \xi$ for some $\xi \in \Omega^1(M)$. The (time-dependent) vector field $X_t$ in $T^{*} M$ which integrates to the isotopy in the Moser theorem is determined by $\pi^{*} \xi + \iota_{X_t} \omega = 0$. Immediately we get that $X_t$ does not actually depend on $t$ (since $\pi^{*} \xi$ doesn't). We also see that $X$ is a vertical vector field (i.e. points in the direction of fibers). Now it's not hard to see that it'll be constant along each fiber (essentially since $\pi^{*} \xi$ is) and hence complete; so we do not need the compactness requirement.

Comment: @ Pedro: Thank you for your response. I don't see why $X_{t}$ is time-independent though. Shouldn't it be $\omega_{t}$ instead of $\omega$ in the formula that determines $X_{t}$?

Comment: First we solve $i_Y\omega+\pi^*\xi=0$ and we find that $Y$ is vertical using local chart. So, $i_Y\pi^*\xi=0$, hence $Y=X_t$.